# Как скачать обложку

Tags: java, android

Есть ссылка с TikTok например https://vm.tiktok.com/WeAnGo/ и мне нужно получить ссылку на обложки или привью jpg, png, через API TikTok смотрел там такого нет, чтоб получить информацию об видео

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(new URL("https://vm.tiktok.com/WeAnGo/").toString());
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
Bitmap thumbBitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(-1); //
```

Только надо отловить `Exception`'ы

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#getFrameAtTime(long))